# Image order in Gallery

Tags: gallery

Using 4.0.4 on generic Chinese tablet.  I have holiday pictures in a folder as an album, they show in reverse order - latest through to earliest - making slideshow worthless. The filenames are in the correct sequence as are the date/time stamps.  Any ideas on correcting this please.  It seems that a friends phone does the same!  Is this a bug in Gallery?